# Reuse serialized c# object in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq-to-sql, xml-deserialization

I am planning to serialize a C# object as XML and store it in a SQL XML datacolumn. Now my question is:

If it is properly serialized into XML format, is it possible to do `JOINs` ?

Main reason to store it in XML column is relatively small level to query this data, and avoid adding additional table to store data in sql.

A) Using SQL query?

- Do I have to store XML schema in SQL in order to run query against this column type ?

b) Using Linq

- Is it possible to serialize it and then choose needed column for join ?

  Is there a better alternative to query this data type from linq ?

Comment: Object to XML is serialization. XML to object is deserialization.

Comment: @IanNelson thank Ian, I got carried away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think XML schemas are required, I believe you can issue XPATH queries against an XML column at will. With regard to LINQ, are you talking about querying the object pre-serialisation, post-serialisation or once it's in SQL?

There are some decent alternatives such as db40 and Mongo which might also meet your needs without the weight of MS SQL Server.